# Tweepy API Cursor Object has no attribute '__self__'

Tags: python, tweepy

I have installed tweepy 2.3 directly from Git and have just started learning how to use it but I get an error when I try to get tweets from a user defined twitter id. Here's my code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.cursor import Cursor


#Necessary information
consumer_key = "a"
consumer_secret = "b"
access_token = "c"
access_token_secret = "d"

#setup
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)



result = Cursor(api.user_timeline, id="BarackObama").items(50)
for status in result:
    print(status.text)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/Resources/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy-2.3-py2.7.egg/tweepy/cursor.py", line 190, in next
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy-2.3-py2.7.egg/tweepy/cursor.py", line 105, in next
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__self__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/svven/tweepy/blob/master/README.md) GitHub repo that fixes the error.